# Missing $ inserted. ...3mm]{\includegraphics[width=4.002cm]{6a}}

Tags: math-mode, errors, captions

I can not remove this error:

> Missing $ inserted. ...

I have already used:

```
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {D:/Users/test/} }
```

and my code is:

```
\begin{figure}[t]
    \centering
    \subfloat[\kappa_1=0.01mm]{\includegraphics[width=4cm]{6a}} 
    \hfill
    \subfloat[\kappa_2=0.02mm]{\includegraphics[width=3.9cm]{6b}} \\
    \caption{Test}\label{foo}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please as usual here show us a short compilable code we can test on our own computer. Have you tried to use `\subfloat[$\kappa_1$=0.01mm]{\includegraphics[width=4cm]{6a}}`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `$\kappa_1$` and `$\kappa_2$` to get rid of that error message.

See the following mwe:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[t]
    \centering
    \subfloat[$\kappa_1$=0.01mm]{\includegraphics[width=4cm]{example-image-a}} 
    \hfill
    \subfloat[$\kappa_2$=0.02mm]{\includegraphics[width=3.9cm]{example-image-b}} \\
    \caption{Test}\label{foo}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

and its result:

[image]